# Django middleware - exclude for specific path

Tags: python, django

I have implemented a health check for Django web server

The health check by default calls all the middlewares which executes cache invalidation, db calls, feature flags calls etc.

I would like to avoid calling the middlewares for this specific path

For every middleware there is `__call__` method implemented where the code is executed

where can I define what middleware will be executed based on path?

Answer (score 0):

My solution for the problem is using a decorator

```
def skip_for_paths(paths_to_exclude):
"""
decorator for skipping middleware based on path
"""
def decorator(f):
    def check_if_health(self, request):
        if request.path in paths_to_exclude:
            return self.get_response(request)
        return f(self, request)
    return check_if_health
return decorator
```

and in the middleware:

```
    @skip_for_paths(['/workflows/v1/health/'])
def __call__(self, request):
    # Code to be executed for each request before

    response = self.get_response(request)

    response['Cache-Control'] = "no-cache"
    # Code to be executed for each request/response after
    # the view is called.
```